# Camel doesn't terminate Java process with max idle seconds property (Spring-Boot)

Tags: spring-boot, jvm, apache-camel, integration

I have a Spring boot application that uses Apache camel. It is a standalone application that polls a directory with Camel File Component, processes the content and send it Kafka with Camel Kafka Component. I would like the application to be short lived so I want it to self terminate after given idle seconds. I am using camel-spring-boot-starter dependency so I can setup max idle seconds in application properties:

`camel.springboot.duration-max-idle-seconds=20`

After 20 seconds I see that the camel context and my webserver(used for actuator) are shutdown gracefully but the java process doesn't return an exit code 0. The process hangs like this forever.

Using a similar property, if I set `camel.springboot.duration-max-seconds=20` this time, camel context and the web-server shutdown logs are exactly the same and shuts down correctly and the Java process returns an exit code 0, which I was expecting.

Do you happen to run into a similar behavior? Why duration-max-idle-seconds does a graceful shutdown of camel but doesn't terminate the Java process?

Comment: Take a thread dump to see what non-daemon threads are running.

Comment: Yeah I think we recently fixed this for the upcoming Camel 3.2.0 release together with this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CAMEL-14642

Comment: I took two thread dumps when running with two different properties mentioned above. When I reach the max idle seconds with ```camel.springboot.duration-max-idle-seconds=20``` only non-daemon is _DestroyJavaVM_ with state RUNNABLE:  
"DestroyJavaVM" #72 prio=5 os_prio=0 tid=0x00000000249ad000 nid=0x7d4c waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE  
Thread dump taken with ```camel.springboot.duration-max-seconds=20```, gives a different picture:
_SpringContextShutdownHook_ non-daemon is RUNNABLE whereas _DestroyJavaVM_ is WAITING (on object monitor)

Comment: @ClausIbsen I am able to reproduce that issue but it is valid for the property _duration-max-seconds_. My issue is when I use _duration-max-idle-seconds_ for which I just want the application terminate and exit after being idle for a while. I found a dirty workaround by implementing a custom _ApplicationListener_ where I exit the system myself if the _ApplicationEvent_ is a _ContextClosedEvent_. However, this approach overrides the Camel's graceful shutdown in which it stops and shuts the routes down first, destroys the beans and the CamelContext.

Comment: @apangin there is also another non-daemon thread in the thread dump. _pool-2-thread-1_ with state TIMED_WAITING (parking). I think this thread has been created by _MainDurationEventNotifier_ to stop Camel. I also see the log(with wrong logger name _MainLifecycleStrategy_) "Duration max idle triggering shutdown of the JVM." However, I am not sure if it can cause Java process to hang.

Comment: @TanzhuOzen did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing this issue on Camel 3.2.0 and updating to 3.6.0 solves the problem.